# Hide bottom tab item based on AsyncStorage item using React Navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a role based authentication that should display or hide an item from the bottom tab based on the user role.

The user information is coming from `AsyncStorage`

```
const user = (await AsyncStorage.getItem('user'))
```

I just wanted to hide `ArtistStack` if `user.role === 'something'`

```
const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    HomeStack, 
    ArtistStack,
    ProfileStack,
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: Colors.primary,
      showLabel: false,
    },
  }
)
```